# Manual update in physics scene doesnt work properly in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I need to manually update a 2D physics scene in unity using the script below:

```
public class ManualPhysicsSceneUpdate : MonoBehaviour
{
    string autoPhysicsScene = "my-physics-scene;
    PhysicsScene2D physicsScene;
    public GameObject objectsPrefab;

    private GameObject objInstance; 

    void Start()
    {  
        var scene = SceneManager.CreateScene(autoPhysicsScene, 
            new CreateSceneParameters( LocalPhysicsMode.Physics2D )); 
        physicsScene = scene.GetPhysicsScene2D();
        objInstance = Instantiate(objectsPrefab, transform);
        objInstance.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        objInstance.transform.SetParent(null);

        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(obj, scene);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //physicsScene.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime); 
    } 

    [ContextMenu("Update 10000 Iteration")]
    public void Iteration10000()
    {
        Iteration(10000);
    }

    public void Iteration(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            physicsScene.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        }
    }
}
```

There is also a bounce handle script that is attached to a ball object:

```
public class BounceHandle2D : MonoBehaviour
{  
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector3 beforeCollisionVelocity;

    private void Awake()
    { 
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    } 

    private void FixedUpdate() => beforeCollisionVelocity = rb.velocity; 

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {   
        var reflected = Vector2.Reflect(beforeCollisionVelocity.normalized, 
                                        col.contacts[0].normal);  
        rb.velocity = reflected.normalized * rb.velocity.magnitude; 
    }
}
```

I add force to ball using this:

```
targetPlayer.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(-50, 100) * 10);
```

When I call **physicsScene.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime)** in **FixedUpdate** method everything is correct and If I call **Iteration10000()** method, It produces completely wrong results but always the same as before.

[image]

*The red ball is in a correct position and white ball is the simulation result when calling Iteration10000()*

Note that if i disable the BounceHandle2D script, everything works fine in both cases. Do you have any idea what is happening here?

Thank you in advance.

Repository: https://github.com/mesutrk95/unity-physics-simulation

Comment: have you made sure you call it exactly `10000` times in `FixedUpdate`?

Comment: @derHugo, That ball stops after almost 1000 updates and more updates do not make a difference in the result

Comment: From your code I don't see why the ball should stop at all .. you are applying back its velocity anyway ... what I don't really get though tbh is the `FixedUpdate` .. why not simply `rb.velocity = Vector2.Reflect(rb.velocity, col.contacts[0].normal);` ? I wouldn't rely on the call order of `FixedUpdate` and `OnCollisionEnter2D` especially when going through simulate

Comment: @derHugo AngularDrag in the ball rigid body has been set to 1.0, Then the scene will be idle after a while

Comment: hm interesting since `AngularDrag` should only reduce its `angularVelocity` .. you probably mean just the `Drag` and then it makes sense I agree

Comment: derHugo,`rb.velocity` denotes the velocity after collision, that it already reflected.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason, According to Unity's official documentation, The Unity engine doesn't call  `FixedUpdate()` when we manually update physics by calling `physicsScene.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime)`.

Then the last velocity variable `beforeCollisionVelocity` will be a zero vector.